# Print stop/starts after 3Dtouch installation

Tags: bltouch, 3dtouch

Just installed and set up a 3Dtouch on my home-built Prusa. I followed several articles as well as YouTube videos. I can get ABL to work well but printing has become a problem. Each print starts then stops every few seconds and then continues. Having checked a terminal the motherboard is running an `M119` every so often and reports the Z endstop triggered. This continues throughout the print stop/starting. The setup worked fine with the original Pinda and steel sheet, but I wanted to change it to a textured glass for better adhesion.

Tech info:

- Prusa Mk3 clone
- 3Dtouch
- BTT SKR1.3
- Marlin 2.1.
- Mattercontrol (slicer)

Comment: Do note that you cannot use the `M119` when you use a touch sensor, it doesn't give you information on the Z-axis endstop status.

Comment: Agreed. I thought the reporting to the PC might be interrupting the print for a second before continuing.

Comment: I seem to have narrowed it down to Mattercontrol. Using Cura as the host, small test prints work fine.